# How to handle null objects for entities in php

Tags: php, design-patterns, orm, entity

I have an Entity class that maps records from MySQL database. For example, a class User that inherits an Entity class would map table user.

```
class User extends Entity
{
    function init(){ $this->_table = 'user';}
}
```

When I map an object with id 30 i use

```
$user = new User(30);
```

What is the best way to handle when object id 30 is not available (let's say it is deleted).

1. Throw an exception, "This object is not available"
2. Return a null object.

A solution or a set of solutions with pros/cons would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use exceptions in cases like this because the exception can contain the various reasons the object is unavailable.  A null object you'll have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Throwing exceptions means that an exceptional situation occurred in your application. In my opinion an object with a specific ID not existing is not an exceptional situation. I would go with returning a null object.

And the mechanism for throwing/catching exceptions comes with a performance penalty.

Comment: I personally find null-objects annoying. An exception is fine as long as this is what an application is expecting. There are situations, where I want this object to returned with an ->getId() == 0.

Comment: So, your solution would be ` $obj = new Article($id); if (is_null($obj)) echo $obj->getTitle()`

Comment: $obj = new Article($id); if (!is_null($obj)) echo $obj->getTitle()

Answer (score 0):

Throw an exception. This way you can catch it wherever you're trying to construct the User object, and decide what to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I prefer to return an object with an error code property.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to say without knowing the design of your program, such as where these "ID's" are coming from, how they are generated, etc.
The pros/cons here are based on the design of your program and your needs for the given situation. Once you assess those, you can determine what is best for you.

Comment: Let's say that on a widget's options I have saved an article id. In the logic of view I'm using $obj = new Article($saved_id); I showuld not show anything if is not available any more that id. So what's best:
     `
$obj = new Article($id); 
if ($obj) echo $obj->getTitle(); 
`
or 
`
    try
    {
}
catch(NullObjectException $e)
{
//do nothing, maybe log error
}`

Comment: So the case of the `id` not existing is likely and exceptional. In this case, I don't think you can do both. I would throw an exception so that you don't have to check for a `null` object throughout the rest of your code.